# STL algorithm to find all tuples with first element within a range

Tags: c++, stl

I have a list of tuple, the list was sorted based on the first element of the tuple but the second and last elements are in random order. Now I want to find all tuples with the first element within a range, i.e. return all tuples for (`tuple.first>-X` and `tuple.first<X`). Among all these returning tuples, I need to find the maximum and minimum value in the second element of the tuples. How can a STL algorithm implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is already sorted, you can use `equal_range` to get a pair of iterators that delimit the range of "interesting" tuples:

```
It const begin = std::lower_bound(list.begin(), list.end(),
                                  [X](Tuple const& t) {
                                      return t.first > -X;
                                  });

It const end = std::upper_bound(begin, list.end(),
                                [X](Tuple const& t) {
                                    return t.first < X;
                                });

std::pair<It,It> const range = std::make_range(begin, end);
```

Then, you can simply iterate over this range, and register the minimum and maximum values that you see:

```
int min = INT_MAX, max = INT_MIN;

for (Tuple const& t: range) {
  if (t.second < min) { min = t.second; }
  if (t.second > max) { max = t.second; }
}

// min and max are correctly set
```

So... it's not a single STL algorithm.

*Note: `std::min_element` and `std::max_element` do exist, but that would mean looping twice over the range, it's certainly feasible though.*

```
Tuple const& min = *std::min_element(range.first, range.second,
                       [](Tuple const& left, Tuple const& right) {
                           return left.second < right.second;
                       });

Tuple const& max = *std::max_element(range.first, range.second,
                       [](Tuple const& left, Tuple const& right) {
                           return left.second < right.second;
                       });

// Or as noted by Vitali, slightly more efficient:

auto const minmax = std::minmax_element(range.first, range.second, 
                       [](Tuple const& left, Tuple const& right) {
                           return left.second < right.second;
                       });

Tuple const& min = *minmax.first;
Tuple const& max = *minmax.second;
```

Note that it gives a tuple, and not the `.second` member.

Comment: HI Matthieu M. the first code doesn't pass my compiler (VS2011). by the way, how do I pass the third parameter such that I modify the compare function as (t.first-thirdparameter>-X) && (t.first-thirdparameter)<X ? Thanks.

Comment: @user1285419: you are right, equal range does not seem to cut it because the range is not sorted by absolute value here. You have to use `lower_bound` and `upper_bound instead.

Comment: I would use minmax_element which gives you O(max(floor(3/2(N−1)), 0)) as opposed to O(2N)

Comment: @Vitali: Indeed! Let me amend my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
ListType::iterator itrFirst = std::find_if( ls.begin(), ls.end(), boost::bind( &TupleType::get< 0 >, _1 ) >= rangeStart );
ListType::iterator itrLast = std::find_if( itrFirst, ls.end(), boost::bind( &TupleType::get< 0 >, _1 ) > rangeEnd );
for( ;itrFirst != itrLast; ++itrFirst ) // Print keys for elements in range
    std::cout << itrFirst->get<0>() << std::endl;
```

I presume boost:: can be replaced with std:: if you have a recent compiler ( I don't ).

Comment: Thank you a lot. The code looks neat :) I found that it might be too complicate for me to use tuple in my code. So I modify it to use pair instead. 
[code]
vector<pair<double, double> > ls; 
vector<pair<double, double> >::iterator itrFirst = std::find_if( ls.begin(), ls.end(), boost::bind( &pair<double, double>::first, _1 ) >= -0.01 );
vector<pair<double, double> >::iterator itrLast = std::find_if( itrFirst, ls.end(), boost::bind( &pair<double, double>::first, _1 ) > 0.01 );

[/code]

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What's your compiler error? This code requires boost to work, or if you have a compiler post c++98 you can instead include <functional> and use std::bind.